# PlayerPrefs cleared after yield

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a weird issue in Unity 2019 (2019.3.11f1), where PlayersPrefs is cleared after running yield in a method started from Coroutine:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("user_id"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("user_id", System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
            Debug.Log("UID1: " + PlayerPrefs.GetString("user_id"));
        }

        StartCoroutine(DoSomething());
    }

    IEnumerator DoSomething()
    {
        Debug.Log("UID2: " + PlayerPrefs.GetString("user_id"));
        yield return null;
        Debug.Log("UID3: " + PlayerPrefs.GetString("user_id"));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

UID1 and UID2 are printed just fine, but UID3 is empty... Also, the key does not exist in the next run.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For sanity sake; Is this the actual code you are using on which you are encountering the problem? Running the code myself I have no issues. I get all three expected logs on the first iteration, and get `UID2:` and `UID3:` on the second. Do you have any other scripts that are accessing the `user_id` playerpref, potentially clearing it. Or calling a `PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll` somewhere?

Comment: Remy, asked a moderator to give you the points instead of my own answer since I must have missed it... Thanks!

Comment: All good, no need to ask the mods for that (they already have it busy!), glad I could help. I've converted my comment to a full answer with some more details for future references :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code locally and it worked for me, the most likely cause is that you are making a call to the player prefs somewhere else in your code that either:

- Unsets the value of `user_id`
- Removes the key using `PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("user_id")`
- Removes all player prefs using `PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();`

The reason your `UID1` and `UID2` are returning the expected value is because the other code clearing the PlayerPref is called while your coroutine is yielding, before executing the code to read `UID3` in the next frame.